# WebSocket Client dont receive data

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I got a websocket server written in c# and a simple client to test it.

I successfully made the handshake, and it triggers the onopen event in client.
But when i send data to the client it just ignores it.

Like:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
clientSocket.Send(data);
```

In the client it never triggers the event `onmessage`.

I already tried to put the first byte of text `0x00` and last `0xFF`, but no diferences.
I tried to send an array of bytes with `byte[0] = 0x00` first, then the message and then `byte[0] = 0xFF`. But again no diferences.

Someone knows how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is that code written in try catch? If yes what type of error you getting? Also provide your code.

Comment: `byte[0] = 0xFF` Are you sure? Setting the first byte twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution.
The problem is that in this version of draft messages should goes into a frame.
There is a several bytes that should come first.
This article helped me, hope it can help someone else:
http://blog.vunie.com/implementing-websocket-draft-10

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a websocket client library directly.
http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/